# I wanted to add text 'Add Photo' before the camera icon

Tags: flutter, file-upload, imagepicker

I want to add text 'Add photo' before the camera icon. How could I add in the given code below.

```
InkWell(
                        onTap: (){
                          _pickImage();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                            ),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 70),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.photo_camera,
                              size: 25,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),


                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `Row` here:

```
child: Row (
  children: [
    Text('Add photo'),
    Icon(
      Icons.photo_camera,
      size: 25,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ],
)
```